# Perform Segue from Root View Controller of a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIPageViewController and have a button in it. Whenever the button is pressed I want to perform a Segue from the parent view controller (which has a navigation controller embedded) to the next view controller in the navigation stack. I also want to be able to pass data through the segue. I've tried a couple of things but I'm very new to iOS development and have not been successful at all.

Comment: I found this tutorial helpful http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_UIPageViewController_Application

Comment: It is a helpful tutorial indeed but not relevant here. I have the page setup and it's working perfectly. I just setup a IBAction in the PageViewController and need to perform a Segue from the parent to view when the IBAction is called.

Comment: So did you add the button in storyboard? If so you don't need an IBAction method. Just right click on the button and drag to the next view controller and select "push".

Comment: If that does deal with the segue problem then your next issue was passing data. You do that in the UIViewController method  -performSegueWithIdentifier:

Comment: The problem with that method is that I can't pass data through the segue. What I need to achieve at the end is that I need to change the title of the next view controller depending on what page the button was pressed on.

Comment: You can pass data. I'll stick some code up in a moment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant -prepareForSegue:

Comment: Sorry, I replied before I read your second reply. I see what you mean. I connect the UIButton from the storyboard directly. I give the new Segue an identifier and I pass data using the prepareForSegue method using the identifier. Sounds good. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Exactly. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the segue in your storyboard and give it a unique identifier and the put that in the code below.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
    // get a reference to the destination View Controller
    UIViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    XXYourViewControllerSubclass *yourVC = (XXYourViewControllerSubclass*)destinationVC;
    // create the data and pass it to the view controller
    id someData = // create your data (unless you have a property holding it already)
    [yourVC acceptData:(id)someData]; // make a public method on your VC subclass to accept the data
}
// after this method has returned the seque will be performed
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Can u please write it in swift ? I having trouble to convert this code